# How to put "printf" on console Debug QEMU on Eclipse STM32F4

Tags: stm32, eclipse

I create a blinky project to test a qemu simulator, but my printf`s not showing in the debug console. I create a project like official tutorial GNU MCU Eclipse.

```
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // By customising __initialize_args() it is possible to pass arguments,
  // for example when running tests with semihosting you can pass various
  // options to the test.
  // trace_dump_args(argc, argv);

  // Send a greeting to the trace device (skipped on Release).
  trace_puts("Hello ARM World!");

  // The standard output and the standard error should be forwarded to
  // the trace device. For this to work, a redirection in _write.c is
  // required.
  puts("Standard output message.");
  fprintf(stderr, "Standard error message.\n");

  // At this stage the system clock should have already been configured
  // at high speed.
  trace_printf("System clock: %u Hz\n", SystemCoreClock);

  timer_start();

  blink_led_init();

  uint32_t seconds = 0;

  // Infinite loop
  while (1)
    {
      blink_led_on();
      timer_sleep(seconds == 0 ? TIMER_FREQUENCY_HZ : BLINK_ON_TICKS);

      blink_led_off();
      timer_sleep(BLINK_OFF_TICKS);

      ++seconds;
      // Count seconds on the trace device.

      printf("My printf");

      trace_printf("Second %u\n", seconds);
    }
  // Infinite loop, never return.
}
```

[image]

Comment: Here is a minimal, fully automated, UART example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/newlib-examples/tree/44d6c25f36b2137f3a0f1a6efb461f7373c61ada

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard feature of the C library. Standard output (and input) is line buffered by default, therefore it will be held in a buffer (by the target libc) until/unless you do one of the following

- send a newline character to stdout
- call `fflush(stdout)`
- turn off buffering with `setbuf()` or `setvbuf()` (do this before the very first output)

Standard error is not buffered, unless you tell the library otherwise, therefore you'd see every character immediately even if there is no newline.

Comment: Yes! I just called printf("My Pritnf\n") and this went to output console. This works.